# Android Front end for matplotlib python plot display

Tags: python, android, matplotlib, plot

I am new to android development and matplotlib. I want to display the matplotlib python plot in android app layout as an interactive plot(with zoom and scroll functionality).

Is it possible with Chaquopy? If possible then how to do it! Please help me.

I wrote a python script where I make the plot with datasets, scaling, zoom controls and return it as string. Then I receive that result of py script in my android class and make it visible in an image view in android app. I can display the plot like this way but in this way the plot is not interactive its just an image and its not possible to zoom in /out a specific portion of the plot that we could do for normal matplotlib python plot. How to do it in Android Studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since matplotlib doesn't have any built-in support for Android, I don't think it's possible to do this directly.

Instead, you could add some buttons to your user interface to allow the user to zoom and scroll, and re-generate the image whenever they're clicked.